# how to split polyline where start/endpoints of the linestring touches or intersects with the nearby lines in qgis using python or postgis

Tags: pyqgis, postgresql, qgis-2, postgis-2.0

I have a line layer and i want to find if the start/endpoints of the  linestring  touches or intersects with the nearby lines in qgis using python.

I have tried the following code but it is not working.

```
def linestouches(l_layer):
    ln_spIndex = QgsSpatialIndex()
    for ln in l_layer.getFeatures():
        ln_spIndex.insertFeature(ln)
        #print(ln['id'])
    for ln in l_layer.getFeatures():
        list1 = []
        print "****ln_id = ",ln['id']
        ln_geom = ln.geometry().asPolyline()
        ln_id = ln.id()
        print('The line id is',ln_id)
        # extract the segments seg_start, seg_end of the line
        X,Y = ln_geom[0],ln_geom[-1]
        print X,Y
        list1.append([X,Y])
        list1 = [val for sublist in sect_list for val in sublist]
        for i in list1:
            print( 'the i is',i)
            nearestgIds = ln_spIndex.nearestNeighbor(i,2)
            print('the nearest ids are',nearestgIds)
            for nid in nearestgIds:
                if nid != ln_id:
                    sel_feat = nid
                else:
                    pass
            print('the selected feat id is',sel_feat)
            l_layer.select(sel_feat)
            vertex_geom = QgsGeometry.fromPoint(i)
            sel_feat = l_layer.selectedFeatures()[0]
            sel_feat_geom = sel_feat.geometry()
            print('vertex_geom,sel_feat_geom',vertex_geom,sel_feat_geom)
            if sel_feat_geom.st_ intersects(vertex_geom):
                print('intersects')
            else:
                print('not intersects')
```

Please tell me what is going wrong here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determining if line is snapped to nearest linestring in PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/255179/determining-if-line-is-snapped-to-nearest-linestring-in-pyqgis)

Comment: I think this is 'unclear' due to the fact that your question title and content do not match. The content is clearly duplicate to the question linked by @JGH, but the title is something else.