# Determining if line is snapped to nearest linestring in PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-2

I have a polyline layer and I want to find if a linestring is snapped to the nearest linestring or not in QGIS. How can I do that in QGIS?

I am checking for the intersection but the intersection code is not working because the line string is snapped. So I want to find the snapping linestrings.

```
def lines(l_layer):
    for ln1,ln2 in itertools.combinations(l_layer.getFeatures(),r=2):
        print ln1.id(),ln2.id()
        if ln1.geometry().intersects(ln2.geometry()):
            print('intersects')
            print ln1.id(),ln2.id()
        else:
            print('not intersects')
```

Here I am not getting one linestring which is touching with the other because it is snapped and it doesn't have the vertex. So I want to find if the line is snapped.

Comment: What crs are you using on your project and for both layers?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
tolerance = #insert your snapping tolerance here
if ln1.geometry().distance(ln2.geometry()) < tolerance:
    print('intersects')
```